# Simple XML Sort based on Name

Tags: php, xml, sorting, simplexml

I am trying to sort a list of databases and documents in each database by the databasename.
Then print them out in a tabled format

here is the xml

```
<responsedata>
<databases>
<database>
<name>Test</name>
<documents>0</documents>
</database>
−
<database>
<name>Test2</name>
<documents>0</documents>
</database>
</databases>
</responsedata>
```

here is my current code that lists the databases and documents without the sort and print them out in a list.

```
$request_url = "http://255.255.255.255/xmlfile";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url)

foreach ($xml->responsedata->databases->database as $db) {

          echo"<tr><td>",$db->name,"</td><td>",$db->documents,"</td></tr>\n";
  }
```

//

Comment: `<xsl:sort select="name" data-type="text" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dbs = array();

foreach ($xml->responsedata->databases->database as $db) {
  $dbs[(string)$db->name] = $db;
}

ksort($dbs);

foreach ($dbs as $db) {
  echo"<tr><td>",htmlentities($db->name),"</td>",
      "<td>",htmlentities($db->documents),"</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: There is no output possibly something wrong with $dbs and $db?

Comment: @Bucabear: See changed code. You must explicitly cast the `$db` (which is of type `SimpleXMLElement`) to string or PHP won't accept the array index.