# php simplexml get maximum value

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, max

How is it possible to get the highest existing guid value from an existing xml file (SimpleXml).

xml-structure example:

```
<xml blabla>
 <blog name="">
  <post>
   <guid>3</guid>
   <author></author>
   <content>...</content>
  </post>
  <post>
   <guid>1</guid>
   <author></author>
   <content>...</content>
  </post>
 </blog>
```

I tried the following ($xml is an SimpleXml Object)
    max($xml->xpath(/blog/post/guid));
but this seems to be no array...

any suggestions? Is there an way to handle it per xpath? My google search wasn't successful.

Comment: `max()` is a function you should use **within** the XPath expression

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple XML Sort based on Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338699/simple-xml-sort-based-on-name)

Comment: @slhck PHP's libxml doesnt support XPath 2.0

Comment: more results http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+simplexml+sort

Comment: @Gordon it is no duplicate. I want to get a maximum int value not a sorted list...

Comment: @NaN: the principle stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use array_map('intval'... to feed max() with something it "understands".

```
<?php
$xml = getDoc();
$ns = $xml->xpath('//blog/post/guid');
$ns = array_map('intval', $ns);
echo max($ns);

function getDoc() {
    return new SimpleXMLElement( <<< eox
<xml>
 <blog name="">
  <post>
   <guid>3</guid>
   <author></author>
   <content>...</content>
  </post>
  <post>
   <guid>1</guid>
   <author></author>
   <content>...</content>
  </post>
  <post>
   <guid>99</guid>
   <author></author>
   <content>...</content>
  </post>
  <post>
   <guid>47</guid>
   <author></author>
   <content>...</content>
  </post>
 </blog>
</xml>
eox
    );
}
```